# Why curls fails to verify google access token whereas browser succeeds?

Tags: google-oauth, php-curl

with this simple code I manage to get Google's access tokens.
See the code:

```
public function authenticate($code = null) {
  if (!$code) {
     if ($this->log)
        error_log(__CLASS__ . '::authenticate() error: $code is null.');
     return false;
  }
  $client_id = $this->token->get('client_id');
  $client_secret  = $this->token->get('client_secret');
  $redirect_uri = $this->token->get('redirect_uri');
  $url = $this->token->get('token_endpoint');
  $curlPost = 'client_id=' . $client_id . '&client_secret=' . $client_secret . '&redirect_uri=' . $redirect_uri . '&code='. $code . '&grant_type=authorization_code';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);
  $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
  $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);
  $data = \json_decode($buffer, true);
  if ($http_code != 200) {
     $log = __CLASS__ . '::authenticate() error: http code not 200. Responded: '.print_r($data, true);
     $return = false;
  } else {
     $this->auth = $data;
     $return = true;
     $log = __CLASS__ . '::authenticate() returns '.$return.' and sets this->auth='.print_r($data, true);
  }
  if ($this->log)
     error_log($log);
  return $return;
}
```

you can see my project [there](https://github.com/centurianii/googleclient) with a test file.

My question is about the `verify()` function.
When I want to verify Google's access token by typing in the browser sth like `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?access_token=....` **I get immediately a response from Google** but when I try the following function with cURL it fails miserably:

```
public function verify($access_token = null) {
  if (!$access_token) {
     if ($this->log)
        error_log(__CLASS__ . '::verify() error: $access_token is null.');
     return false;
  }
  $url = $this->token->get('verify_endpoint');
  $curlPost = 'access_token='. $access_token;
  //$curlPost = \http_build_query(array('access_token' => $access_token));
  //$curlPost = array('access_token' => $access_token);
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?'.$curlPost);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
  $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);
  $data = \json_decode($buffer, true);
  if ($http_code != 200) {
     $log = __CLASS__ . '::verify() error: http code not 200. Responded: '.print_r($data, true);
     $return = false;
  } else {
     $this->verify = $data;
     $log = __CLASS__ . '::verify() sets this->verify='.print_r($data, true);
     $return = true;
  }
  if ($this->log)
     error_log($log);
  return $return;
}
```

Has this sth to do with cURL? Any answer is welcomed.

Just to clarify: **browser request `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?access_token=...` or with `?id_token=...` always succeeds BUT not cURL** with the **proper** tokens in the query part of course.

Comment: I can't help with an answer. However in the first code block this: `$curlPost = 'client_id=' . $client_id . '&client_secret=' ......` is bad because you're not encoding URI string. Just let `$curlPost` an associative array an pass it `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);` letting curl do the URI encoding job

Comment: $url = $this->token->get('verify_endpoint'); <-- what is that?   The only way to verify an access token is to make an api call.    Which api call are you making and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, the code uses some helper classes as in github project (https://github.com/centurianii/googleclient); that's the actual url for verification stored in class GoogleToken

Comment: @Paolo I can authenticate, I can verify with my browser BUT curl still fails on verification with message: Array
(
    [error_description] => Unsupported content with type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------4771c015d2208399
)

Comment: I suspect the way I use curl in verify() is not a clear GET request; at the end I shouldn't verify at all but still I wonder why curl fails?

Answer (score 0):

From your source code [here](https://github.com/centurianii/googleclient/blob/fa1e203c886426217e922045071b2bb97d13b57a/GoogleToken.php)

> $this->set('verify_endpoint', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo');

is calling googles token info end point [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint) is used for validating an id token you appear to be passing it an access token.   This is not going to work.

TBH i dont understand why you would bother validating an access token.  The best way to test if an access token is working is to make the call to the API in question if it doesnt work you will get an error back.  Why would you want to make a call to test if it works then use it if it does work your doubling your requests.

Comment: Ok, I have the access token, I put in my browser: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?access_token=ya29.Gl...` and I can see immediate response! My question is what is going with curl equivalent. You suggest not to do this step?

Comment: I pass `id_token` from browser: succeeds, from curl: fails! I suspect curl does not make a clear GET request here...

Comment: Probably because what you are giving curl isnt an id token its an access token.    Passing an Id_token via a http get will work.     Why are you bothering to test this exactly?

Comment: $curlPost = 'token_id='. $token_id;  <--- try that.   Remember an access token is not a token id

Comment: I log google's response so i can see `Array
(
    [access_token] => ya29.G...O0
    [expires_in] => 3600
    [id_token] => eyJhb...Obg
    [refresh_token] => 1/wLy...9i
    [token_type] => Bearer
)`

Comment: then send id token

Answer (score 0):

***Problems solved!***

After a 2 month searching at last there is an update version of my project wirh `cUrl` problems solved immediately after started to investigate errors sent by the curl environment.

The browser success ringed a bell that probably there was a `DNS` issue as these threads repeatedly showcase this:

1. https://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2016-10/0000.html
2. https://forums.rancher.com/t/dns-caching-issues/1566/8 @vincent
3. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/issues/405
4. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/1184

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932636/how-to-set-hostname-using-php-curl-for-a-specific-ip) discussion from `@sanmai` about `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` actually made it working! Also see [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php); The same is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351152/how-to-manually-resolve-hosts-in-https-connections-in-php) by Luc van Donkersgoed and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390549/set-curl-to-use-local-virtual-hosts) by John Hart.

The tricky parts of response headers on `GET` requests that contain Google's response are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866946/how-can-i-see-the-request-headers-made-by-curl-when-sending-a-request-to-the-ser) and in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request) places.

Curl certificates are downloaded from [there](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).
A discussion for certificates is [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate).

A discussion for debugging `cUrl` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868808/make-curl-output-stderr-to-file-or-string) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl/3760294).

For a discussion of `Expect` header and it's implications you can read [this](https://github.com/openzipkin/docker-zipkin/issues/114) and [that](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2005-06/0074.html).

Now `cUrl` is lightning fast when it connects to google. See my [project](https://github.com/centurianii/googleclient).

My deepest gratitude to all the users who patiently and kindly support the community. You guys are awesome! many thanks!